# Sorting a nested JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array named **"wordsArray"**, contains 5000 words. I am looking for a solution to sort this array based on "Word"."id". We also have "Project"."id" which is not important in our case.
Here is the JSON format of array:

```
{
    "Word":
        {"id":"1","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"4","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"2","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"3","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
};
```

After sorting, it should be something like this:

```
{
    "Word":
        {"id":"1","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"2","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"3","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
},{
    "Word":
        {"id":"4","project_id":"2"},
    "Project":
        {"id":"2","name":"Web"}
};
```

**Update:** ***In JavaScript***

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple sort to perform in any language.

Comment: Have you implemented anything?  What specifically are you having problems with? What language are you working with?

Comment: @KevinB I tried this but not working. I need in JS. `code` wordsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});`code`

Comment: @MikeBrant I tried this but not working. I need in JS. `code` wordsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});`code`

Comment: of course, because a.id and b.id don't exist. Look at the data you're sorting.

Comment: Should be : arr.sort((a,b)=>a.Word.id - b.Word.id)

Comment: Thanks @JoseHermosillaRodrigo .. It works well with a single line :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a specific programming language in mind that you want to do the sorting in?

Because in C# you could load each "Tree" into an array and loop through each index applying a "rank" that you could then use to reorganize the array. Once the array indexes are in order, you could rebuild the original JSON tree, or use the sorted array else where in your code.

If you are using a web language like javascript then there are built in sorting functions that can be used in conjunction with custom functions for ranking like so:

```
Words.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple nested objects, so you need to look inside the object stored at `Word` to get the `id` property used for comparison.  That might look like this:

```
wordsArray.sort(function (a,b) {
    return parseInt(a.Word.id) - parseInt(b.Word.id);    
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work but this one works: arr.sort((a,b)=>a.Word.id - b.Word.id)

Comment: @MajidNasirinejad There is no functional difference other than you are using arrow function syntax and not explicitly parsing the existing string value to numeric values for the comparison. Considering that arrow functions are not fully supported across browsers yet, I would argue my solution better.